# iron-flex-layout doesn't works

Tags: html, css, polymer

I imported these 'iron-flex-layout' html files and polymer, webcomponents.

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
```

also I wrote css too.

```
<link rel="styleseet" href="main.css">
```

in main.css

```
.flex{
 @apply(--layout-horizontal);
 }
```

and wrote codes like demo page.

```
<div class="container flex">
 <div>one</div>
 <div>two</div>
 <div>three</div>
</div>
```

I expected horizontal texts but it doesn't works.
also, there isn't any error on inspector of chrome

what should I do in this situation?

Comment: one progress.
I try to write 
`
<style is="custom-style">
.flex{
@apply(--layout-horizontal);
}
</style>
`
on same .html page and It works well.

is there a bug to import .css file on polymer??

Comment: css import is [deprecated](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#external-stylesheets) in polymer 1.0 and should be removed in 2.x versions

Comment: @a1626 True, but the OP isn't using `<link rel="import" type="css" href="...">` (which is what is deprecated).

Comment: @tony19 OP? Anyways, the way i read the above code is: iron-flex is imported and used in a css file, which even though deprecated should still work in 1.x versions but probably is not working because of support for css3 variables/mixins. If instead of mixin normal properties are written it'll still work. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @a1626 OP = ["Original Poster"](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Original-Poster-(internet-newsgroups-and-message-boards)-(OP).html). You're misreading the deprecation notice on Polymer's site. They're deprecating the Polymer-specific experimental method of importing CSS files: `<link rel="import" type="css">` and **not** general stylesheet linking done with `<link rel="stylesheet">`. The cause of the problem (as the OP discovered on their own) is that the CSS properties are not in a `<custom-style>`, which is required for Polymer to shim the CSS properties properly.

Comment: @tony19 oh...Thanks for the information. But in case of shadow-dom what is the use of external css file? In my short experience with Web development what i got was that external css file is a place where you can keep your shared css. But in case of Polymer `shared-styles` are there for that. And anyways how will css pierce shadow dom?

Comment: @a1626 Yes, you can use an external CSS file with `<link rel="stylesheet">`, and the styles will be scoped to that element when using Shadow DOM (not Shady). The caveat is CSS properties don't work from external CSS. Polymer style modules are indeed another option (recommended even), but there's nothing preventing the user from using `<link rel="stylesheet">`. See [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsrAtK0X014e4LfmreJS?p=preview)

Comment: @tony19 Oh! so the trick is to import the `stylesheet` inside the `template`. Makes sense if you think about it. Thanks a lot for the information.